# why notification delayed on some devices in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating one android application. In that application notification  coming in nexus only other then nexus notification is delayed. so please help me why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Before you venture into a mission to resolve the notification delay on your Android Smartphone or tablet, it is necessary to understand why it happens. For some Android users the notification delays can range between couple of minutes to more than 20 minutes while there are some others who do not receive the updates until they unlock their device. It can be quite inconvenient, for sure.

The Android apps like Facebook, Gmail, and Hangouts rely on Cloud Messaging service of Google to receive and send Push notifications. The fact is, your device needs to connect to Google’s servers and get new updates. This happens at an interval and this interval is the reason for the delay.

Comment: you have any solution  for that? since even though I am using the fcm I am not getting any notification while device is inactive for few mins

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first GCM notification new library or code that google has given on site .If you already implemented then verify first. GCM notifications are received late on some devices.

Answer (score -1):

Wild guess: Does all devices run with the same time (is the time synchronized with a network provider or NTP server)?